# split hhmmss to hh mm ss in c

Tags: c, string, split, integer

I have an integer say 002345 I want it to be split into Hours=00 Mins=23 Sec=45.I tried using "/" and "%" formula methods but it didn't work out since the first two terms are 00 is there any other way.can any one of you present me with a code.
thank you

Comment: `present me with a code`?  Is it your birthday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not asking for conventional method of using "/" and "%". 
Then you could convert the integer time to string and strip out hour, min, sec.

But storing time as simple integer is NOT a good idea, you would miss the leading zeros for hours. Hence its better to use a char array for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char hour[3]={0};
        char min[3]={0};
        char sec[3]={0};

        int time = 2345;

        char timeStr[10] = {0};

        sprintf(timeStr, "%06d", time);

        memcpy(hour, timeStr, 2);
        memcpy(min, timeStr+2,2);
        memcpy(sec, timeStr+4,2);

        printf("%s:%s:%s",hour,min,sec);

}
```

Way i recommend is:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char hour[3]={0};
        char min[3]={0};
        char sec[3]={0};

        char timeStr[] = "002345";

        memcpy(hour, timeStr, 2);
        memcpy(min, timeStr+2,2);
        memcpy(sec, timeStr+4,2);

        printf("%s:%s:%s",hour,min,sec);

}
```

Then convert hour,min, sec to integer using atoi();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your *integer* is `2345` (since leading zeroes are irrelevant), you can just use:

```
hh = val / 10000;
mm = (val / 100) % 100;
ss = val % 100;
```

If instead you have a string (it's unclear because your tags indicate this but there's no mention of it in the question body), you simply call something like `atoi` or `strtol` on each two-character segment.

Comment: Leading zeroes will make the integer octal.

Comment: @YuHao, that's only if you have them in your _code,_ not entered by a user. And, if you have them that way in your code, don't. Use `2345` (with spaces in front if you want them lined up). And if you're worried about `strtol` treating them as octal, don't be - you specify the base explicitly.